# .htaccess: Invalid command 'Auth_MySQL' in XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

My XAMPP version is 5.6.8, PHP 5.6.8, Apache 2.4.12

I have configured a WP website, but when I try to reach the wp-admin panel, in the browser I get "Error 500 - The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script".

In the error log I can see the following error:
 .htaccess: Invalid command 'Auth_MySQL', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

I figured out I need to load mod_auth_mysql module, however, it turns out it is not compatible with my XAMPP version, so I need a different solution.

.htaccess file as follow:

```
IndexIgnore *
Order Deny,Allow
AuthName "XXX"
AuthType Basic
Auth_MySQL On
Auth_MySQL_Authoritative on
Auth_MySQL_Host XXX
Auth_MySQL_Username XXX
Auth_MySQL_Password XXX
Auth_MySQL_DB XXX
Auth_MySQL_Password_Table XXX
Auth_MySQL_Username_Field XXX
Auth_MySQL_Password_Field XXX
Auth_MySQL_Encryption_Types PHP_MD5
Auth_MySQL_Password_Clause " AND ACTIVE=1"
Auth_MySQL_Empty_Passwords Off
AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
AuthUserFile /dev/null
require valid-user
Deny from all
Satisfy any
```

Thank you!

Comment: please provide your `.htaccess` code

Comment: "It turns out it is not compatible with my XAMPP version, so I need a different solution" - It has to be a module that tells the httpd what a AUTH_MySQL directive is. So, find a compatible build of mod_auth_mysql (if you really need it).

Comment: Please add such information to the question text instead of posting a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a compatible build of mod_auth_mysql, so the solution was to remove the directive from .htaccess.